# progress bar in controller loop mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, progress-bar

I was reading several articles on how to add a progress bar, but did not get any example to help.

I have a controller that makes a data import from a csv (over 10000) file, and how to make the implementation for the progress bar on the screen. 
The only thing missing is to implement the progress bar, I have no idea how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Progress bars can be a bit tricky to get to work properly. I see two options that you can do:

1. The easyiest way is to have a progressbar that only shows a animation that indicate to the user that something is still working, but actually it doesn't show you the progress of your long running task, it only animates.
2. The harder way is of course to show a realtime report on how far the progress has come.
   In this case you will have to use the setTimeout() method in javascript to call a function every 2 or 3 second or so, and in that function do a ajax call to a MVC Controller method that can retreive the currently reported progress from your long running task, and then display it in some way in your GUI.

I either case I think you can use the [jQueryUI ProgressBar component](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label).